Spring security, always being redirected to login page no matter what
30/05 Edit: Currently experiencing the following issue: Always redirected to the login page despite seemingly allowing the access to all pages without the requirement of being logged in.
MyUserDetails:
    package com.example.DevNote.security;

import com.example.DevNote.model.Users;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private Users user;

    public MyUserDetails(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()); 

        return Arrays.asList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}

UsersDetailsServiceImpl:
    package com.example.DevNote.security;

import com.example.DevNote.model.Users;
import com.example.DevNote.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Utilisateur introuvable");
        }

        return new MyUserDetails(user);
    }

}

SecurityConfig:
package com.example.DevNote.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                        auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(login -> login.permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout.permitAll())
        ;

        return http.build();
    }

}

UsersController:
package com.example.DevNote.controller;

import com.example.DevNote.DTO.UsersRegistrationDTO;
import com.example.DevNote.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController 

@RequestMapping("/api/users") 
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/register")  

    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody @Validated UsersRegistrationDTO userdto, BindingResult bindingResult) 

    {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) 
        {

            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        }

        try  
        {
            userService.createUser(userdto);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Création du compte utilisateur réussie"); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 

        {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage()); 

        }
    }

}

UsersVueController:
package com.example.DevNote.controller;

import com.example.DevNote.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@RequestMapping("/vue/users")
@Controller
public class UsersVueController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register() {
        return "register";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

}

UserService:
package com.example.DevNote.service;
import com.example.DevNote.DTO.UsersRegistrationDTO;
import com.example.DevNote.model.Role;
import com.example.DevNote.model.Users;
import com.example.DevNote.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserService  {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public Users createUserTestMapping(String username, String email, String password, Role role) {
        Users user = new Users(username, email, password, role);
        usersRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Users createUser(UsersRegistrationDTO dto) throws Exception  

    {
        if (usersRepository.existsByUsername(dto.getUsername()))
        {
            throw new Exception("Le nom d'utilisateur est déjà pris.");
        }
        if (usersRepository.existsByEmail(dto.getEmail()))
        {
            throw new Exception("L'adresse e-mail est déjà utilisée.");
        }

        Role defaultrole = Role.Apprenant;
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(dto.getPassword());
        Users user = new Users(dto.getUsername(), dto.getEmail(), hashedPassword, defaultrole);
        usersRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }

}

Thank you very much in advance

The problem is your controller. You get redirected to /login.html in which you check if you are authenticated, which will trigger another redirect. You are doing the work that the framework is already doing. Ditch the /login, /login.html, /home.html methods.

As a beginner you should also learn and understand that passing jwts to browsers is dangerous and that this entire solution does not exist in the docs and is a homemade security solution from some random blog that has several issues. For instance you can not logout the user.

@M.Deinum Thank you very much for your answer! As adviced, i got rid of the get mapping in the Controller, and put them in a distinct VueController ( using @Controller).  But while i'm not experiencing the too many redirects issue anymore, i still am redirected to the login page no matter what.. i will edit my original post so you can better see what kind of changes i made

@Toerktumlare Thank you! After looking into it, i can definitely see why it's a bad idea

The problem is your controller, you are doing the work that Spring Security already is doing.
Ditch the methods mapping to /login.html, /login, /home.html and let Spring Security handle it. Another issue is is that you are mixing @RestController and @Controller in 1 class, decide what it is or use @Controller with @ResponseBody to the right methods.
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/api/users") 
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UsersController.class.getName());

    @PostMapping("/register")
    @ResponseBody  
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody @Validated UsersRegistrationDTO userdto, BindingResult bindingResult) 

    {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) 
        {

            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        }

        try  
        {
            userService.createUser(userdto);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Création du compte utilisateur réussie"); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 

        {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage()); 

        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "redirect:/testtest.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("/testtest.html")
    public String testtest() {
        logger.info("Accessing the testtest page");
        return "testtest.html";
    }

}

Now it is only Spring Security that is handling the login. You would need to add some view controller to map to the html pages. You can add this to the SecurityConfig.
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer { 

  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home.html");
    registry.addViewController("/login.html").setViewName("login.html")
  } 
}

Now I assume the names of the pages are actually correct. Although I would expect them to be without .html and rendered by something like Thymeleaf and correctly setup view controllers.
